# Vestcom stole the technology from thelamco, inc. without pre-authorization

Tags: patentability

Thomas Paul Eversole was an employee of thelamco, inc. at the time this application for patent was rendered.  He has never been a principle of thelamco and had no authorization from thelamco to sign away any rights we had for developing this product.  We share seek to challenge this patent on the grounds that it has been unlawfully gained without our authorization.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! Your post does not include the number of the patent document in question, please edit the question to include it. More importantly, posting here does **not directly communicate** with either the inventor or the USPTO. To get anywhere with your concerns will require much more than posting here.

Comment: Label US 8261477 is the only patent document on google patents that includes the inventor you name.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to invalidate a patent because it was obtained in violation of an employment contract, through fraud, or through inequitable conduct, you're going to have to file a lawsuit in your local US [Federal] District Court; I highly recommend you get the help of a lawyer to do so.  The USPTO will reexamine a patent only if it's being challenged on the basis of prior art.